# Is there an css trick to emulate CSS4 :blank selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If you want to select nodes without any children you might think about using `:empty`. Meanwhile the behaviour of `:empty` is very annoying as any whitespace will make that rule not apply. `:blank` selector comes here as a saviour but no browser has implemented it yet.

Do you know of any trick to select elements with no other elements inside?

Just to stimulate your imagination: what about something like `.parent:not(:scope > *)`

Comment: It is difficult to select unless CSS parent selector is introduced which is also a CSS4 selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors don't match text nodes, so there is no way to emulate either `:blank`, or `:empty` using a selector.

Taken literally, `.parent:not(:scope > *)` represents any `.parent` element that is not a child of the `:scope` element, whatever that scoping root may be. If the selector is not scoped, then it is equivalent to `.parent:not(:root > *)`, or if it appears in a scoped stylesheet, generally it means any such element that is not a sibling of the `style` element representing this scoped stylesheet.

I suspect you mean something like `.parent:not(:has(> *))`, which will match `.parent` elements that don't have element children, but it doesn't take into account their text contents, again for the same reason I mentioned.

The good news is, while you still have to wait for vendors to get around to implementing this new feature, instead of implementing it in a separate `:blank` pseudo they're considering modifying the functionality of `:empty` instead, provided it doesn't break too many sites. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580185/difference-between-blank-and-empty-pseudo-classes/32580945#32580945).

Answer (score 0):

As BoltClock said there is no way to achieve this with css only for now - it would have been possible with the `:contains()` selector though [it was given up from the CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors).

I know this is not what you was looking for, but here is a jQuery solution that I sometimes use:

```
(function($){
    $.isBlank = function(html, obj){
        return $.trim(html) === "" || obj.length == 0;
    };

    $('li').each(function() {
        if($.isBlank(
            $(this).html(), 
            $(this).contents().filter(function() {
                return (this.nodeType !== Node.COMMENT_NODE);
            })
        )) {
            $(this).addClass('empty');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

See the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vas0y91a/). It target any node that have only spaces in it, or comments, but ignore elements with childs. Probably not perfect but it worked fairly for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed to become more general and accept whitespace with comment.

```
  $('*').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });

  (function($){
    $.isBlank = function(html, obj){
      return $.trim(html) === "" || obj.length == 0;
    };

    $('*').each(function() {
      if($.isBlank(
        $(this).html(), 
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return (this.nodeType !== Node.COMMENT_NODE);
        })
      )) {
           $(this).addClass('blank');
         }
    });
  })(jQuery);
```