# CSS Selector for adding content through :after / :before when HTML element is missing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I would like to add content with the CSS :before selector in case an unsorted HTML list does not have any list items. I can not use :empty, because there might be white space (blanks, newlines, tabs, etc.) between ul and /ul.

As :blank is not implemented yet in most browsers, I need another solution.

Here is an example:

```
// CSS
ul > li::before { content: 'abc'; }   /* how to negate this? */

// 'abc' should not show up
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
</ul>

// 'abc' should show up
<ul>
</ul>
```

The CSS above shows 'abc' when the unsorted list has children. I would like to show 'abc' when the unsorted list has **no** children. So I'm looking for the negation of the CSS line.

Comment: use :not() for negation

Comment: The only option in css is `:empty`. if you could use it, then you could try `ul:empty::after {content:"abc"}`.
Try using Javascript for that strict options.

Comment: `:empty` is for form elements. You cannot achieve this without the use of Javascript. Also, `content` **must** have a real element to work on, and it must be one that can have content. So for example pseudo element do not work on checkboxes and input fields.

Comment: @connexo: `:empty` has nothing to do with form elements.

Comment: True, I was wrong here. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't be possible without the functionality of the `:blank` pseudo-class, I'm afraid.<sup>1</sup>

There are only two possible places you can insert a `::before` pseudo-element in your scenario: in the `ul`, or in a `li`. Since you want to insert the generated content only when *no* `li` elements are present, that leaves you only with `ul`.

Although `::before` and `::after` are inserted before and after an element's descendant elements respectively, [you can't target them relative to those descendant elements with a sibling combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-an-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator/7748876#7748876), and pseudo-elements currently do not support structural pseudo-classes. Which means, in other words, you won't be able to say "prevent `ul::before` from generating content in the presence of one or more `li` elements", nor can you apply the `:only-child` pseudo-class to `ul::before`.

In a situation where one can use `:empty`, it's as simple as

```
ul:empty::before { content: 'abc'; }
```

but since you cannot use `:empty` for the reasons you have given, if you really cannot prevent the whitespace from being generated (e.g. if the content is coming from a WYSIWYG editor or some other transformation that may result in leftover whitespace) you'll have to add a class to any `ul` elements with no children.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>A recent revision to selectors-4 proposes [subsuming the functionality of `:blank` into `:empty` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580185/difference-between-blank-and-empty-pseudo-classes/32580945#32580945), but that likewise is new and requires the cooperation of implementers.</sub>

Comment: Yea, either add a class (or) strip the whitespace characters in the `ul` and let the `ul:empty::after` take effect?